# How to install ChromeDriver in RedHat Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, rhel

I am trying to use selenium on RHEL(Red Hat).

In order to use Chrome browser, I need to install the chromedriver.

Does anyone know how to install this, or what command I need to use? I did not find any resources on this that worked.

Really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Example EL7 : EPEL. 1) `yum install https://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm` 2. `yum install chromedriver` : You get version chromedriver-61.0.3163.100-1.el7.x86_64.rpm .

Answer (score 1):

I followed a process which worked for me.

I am using Redhat 7.4, and I've been through a lot to uninstall and install chrome and firefox, got partially successful with chrome and this is what I tried.

In the Linux terminal

Go to the root by typing

- su -

Then type

- rpm -qa

then (ctrl+f) and search for the keywords "google" or " chrome" or "mozilla" or "firefox" to check whether they are present or not and if they are available, then uninstall( remove ) them by the following command ( if you want to remove them )

- yum remove (theWholeName)

this removes the application

Then install chrome by the following process

type this in terminal

- wget
  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

then a package gets downloaded in your home folder

Then type the following command - this installs the packages

- yum -y install (name of the downloaded folder with extension)

in this case it will be

- yum -y install google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

This installs google chrome and creates an icon under Application->Internet->googleChrome

IMPportant:

technically, by clicking this googlechrome icon- this should open the browser, but it doesn't open the browser for me, I dont know whats the problem and I appreciate any suggestion regarding this issue.

I open google chrome through terminal using this command

- google-chrome --no-sandbox

this opens the chrome browser.

Comment: this is chrome installation. Is there any rpm for chromedriver?

Comment: I just found this link for chromedriver [Link](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=chromedriver). I don't know for what purpose you are using chromedriver. But if you need that chromedriver for Selenium webdriver automated testing. ( this is the scenario where I used chromedriver ), you need to set up path for that Chromedriver in your selenium script.  I would try to help you if you can be more specific.